# Sending string in python

Tags: json, string, sockets, python-3.x

I use the JSON in python version 3.4 for the network programming. The server program was built with another language and it expects to recieve the message in string. I put the JSON query into string and when send it with `sock.send(query.encode())`, but I get the message incorrect data type. Is there exist a way to send the string without converting it?

Comment: You should definitely look into what exactly goes wrong. Probably python does the right thing and encodes that string, e.g. as UTF-8 bytes, before sending it, but the server doesn't understand that.

Comment: Could you post the part of your code for your server and client side both ?

Comment: I don't have the code of the server, they gave me the executable version. I suppose it was built in Java, the error message I get is :
"jade.imtp.leap.JICP.JICPServer$ConnectionHandler run avertissement: uncorrect JICP data type: 123"

Which part of code of the client side do you want to see?